# How do I convert a JOIN on the same table into a Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with records in it.  The desire was to find the records that were exactly the same, except for the time of the 2 records have a difference of less than 2 seconds.

I created a query that works, but as a join, I'd like to switch it to a group by so I can have the records listed vertically, rather than having to go across the entire row to see both records.

I found a solution using a join, but I really would like to see what a solution could be with a group by.  Or any solution that shows both records vertically.

This is the query I have that works

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.*
FROM punches_history p1
INNER JOIN punches_history p2 ON 
    p1.ClockNumber = p2.ClockNumber AND  
    p1.PartNumber = p2.PartNumber  AND  
    p1.Quantity = p2.Quantity  AND 
    p1.YYMMDD = p2.YYMMDD AND  
    ABS(p1.TIMED - p2.TIMED) < 2  
WHERE p1.ClockNumber != '10' AND p1.id = (p2.id + 1) AND p1.CardColor = 'BLU'
ORDER BY p1.YYMMDD desc, p1.ClockNumber desc
```

The WHERE stipulation that needs explaining is `p1.id = (p2.id + 1)` the reason for this logic is so if records 20 and 21 are found records 21, and 20 aren't also found.

Comment: You'd better use `p1.id > p2.id` instead. Just in case difference is more than 1.

Comment: The issue is the duplicate records would always be in order, and directly following each other.  So ```p1.id = (p2.id + 1)``` is correct.

Comment: I don't think you task is solvable with group by: you need to create some "implicating function", that with put both timestamps in the same group. But I don't see any obvious candidate for such function.

Comment: Take a look at the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` window functions, I think that may be what you need.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful here.

Comment: can you be more specific and actually show some of the expected output?  I feel like everyone is guessing at what you want to see and only you know for sure.

Comment: to be clear, it looks like all you care about is that TIMED column is within 2.  It seems like just ordering by the timed column on the puches_hisory would give you the results you expect.  Or do you want a column that says if a row is within 2 of the prior row?  Please give an example of your expected output to clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I think you can pivot this vertically.  Take the id's from the two columns and join back on the table using an `OR`.

```
SELECT ph.*
    FROM (
        SELECT p1.id AS id, p2.id AS id2 
        FROM punches_history p1
             INNER JOIN punches_history p2 ON
                    p1.ClockNumber = p2.ClockNumber AND
                    p1.PartNumber = p2.PartNumber  AND
                    p1.Quantity = p2.Quantity  AND
                    p1.YYMMDD = p2.YYMMDD AND
                    ABS(p1.TIMED - p2.TIMED) < 2
        WHERE p1.ClockNumber != '10' AND p1.id > p2.id AND p1.CardColor = 'BLU'
        ORDER BY p1.YYMMDD DESC, p1.ClockNumber DESC
    ) matches
JOIN punches_history ph ON ph.id = matches.id OR ph.id = matches.id2
ORDER BY ph.YYMMDD DESC, ph.ClockNumber DESC, ph.id
```

You might continue from there to group in some way if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, you want to identify consecutive rows having a set of similar columns with a lesser than 2 seconds gaps - which suggest a gaps-and-island approach.

The idea is to compare the values of the related columns across rows using `lag()` to identify islands.

Here is a query that works for "duplicates" in columns `ClockNumber` and `PartNumber`:

```
select ClockNumber, PartNumber, 
    min(id) from_id, max(id) to_id,
    min(timed) from_timed, max(timed) to_timed,
    count(*) cnt_records_in_group
from (
    select p.*,
        sum(case 
            when LagClockNumber = ClockNumber and LagPartNumber = PartNumbee and Timed - LagTimed < 2
            then 0 else 1
        end) over(order by id) grp               
    from (
        select p.*,
            lag(Timed)       over(order by id) LagTimed,
            lag(ClockNumber) over(order by id) LagClockNumber,
            lag(PartNumber)  over(order by id) LagPartNumber
        from punches_history p
        where ClockNumber != 10 and CardColor = 'BLU'
    ) p
) p
group by ClockNumber, PartNumber, grp
having count(*) > 1
```

This brings one row for each group of (consecutive) duplicate rows, along with starting and ending `id` and `timed`, and count of duplicates per group.

You would typically extend the query with more `lag()`s and more conditions in thé `case` expression to add more columns in the duplicate detection logic (`Quantity`
and `YYMMDD`).

Note: presumably `Timed` is always increasing, so `abs()` is not needed.